# Qt Creator import file not found

Tags: javascript, qt

I am trying to learn Qt QML with Qt Creator. I want to put my javascript functions into a seperate file and 'import' it into the qml world. Have got the code as below for testing how this works.

Trouble is I get the following error when I run the project in Creator...

```
> Starting
> /home/dev/docs/projects/Qt/build-XmlModelView-Desktop-Debug/XmlModelView...
> QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
> QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component qrc:/main.qml:5 Script
> qrc:/MyFuncs.js unavailable qrc:/MyFuncs.js:-1 File not found
```

I have watched videos and followed the Qt online docs and looked at others code, but I can't see what is wrong.

I can only guess that some sort of path is not set correctly, but in the docs it says the default path includes the directory that the QML file is in. My .js and .qml files are in the same directory. Also I tried editing the resource file, but that crashed it completely.

I tried moving the .js file to different locations, absolute path in the import statement. My eyeballs are starting to fall out now.

Oddly **IT DOES WORK** if I use qmlscene to run main.qml

Can anybody help? Here is my code...

main.qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import "MyFuncs.js" as MyFuncs
Window {
    id: window1
    visible: true
    Rectangle {
        id: contentArea
        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea1
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                MyFuncs.myfunc();
            }
        }
}
```

main.cpp file:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

MyFuncs.js File:

```
function myfunc() {
    console.log("function was called")
}
```

Thanks for any help. Lost a whole day, just don't know where to go on.

Comment: Just add the js file to the resources and it will work. Don't edit manually, right click on the resource file in the project browser, and select `add existing file`

Comment: @ddriver Thanks for helping. I tried that. I tried it loads of times and it didn't actually move the file. BUT, I just did it again but clicked on the '/ ' rather than the 'Resources'. This time it added the file!!! AND IT WORKS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*NOTE: 
You can probably just add the JavaScript file to the resources--and then when your project hits complexity where you don't want to recompile for each little change you can do what I did here below:*

You're loading the file via `qrc:/MyFuncs.js` which is the file path to the resource. The problem is that the JavaScript file (likely) was not copied or isn't on your path. (It means you need to bundle it) depending on the path of your scene you might have it show up. As an example here I need to copy my JavaScript and QML to the build directory which is just annoying:

Here's an example of my config file for a moderately sized project:

```
CONFIG += c++11
# Add more folders to ship with the application, here
folder_qml.source = qml
folder_qml.target = /
folder_js.source = js
folder_js.target = /
folder_img.source = img
folder_img.target = /
folder_icon.source = icon
folder_icon.target = /
DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS += folder_qml folder_js folder_img folder_icon
```

Notice the REALLY weird syntax here: this copies the `js`, `qml`, `icon`, and `img` folders,to `/` in the build which you would think dumps those files on the root. Think again! The build directory looks like this:

```
 + debug
 + icon //I added this explicitly
 + img //I added this explicitly
 + js //I added this explicitly
 + qml //I added this explicitly
 + release
 Makefile
 Makefile.Debug
 Makefile.Release
```

Now my application can correctly reference the files as they exist on the path. When running inside the IDE (depending on the setup) you might have the files available to you, you might not.

Here's a snippit from my `main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import com.lightassistant 1.0

import "qrc:/js/lightassistant.js" as LA;
import "qrc:/js/statics.js" as Statics
```

To prove a point here:
If I change the `qrc:/js/statics.js` to `qrc:/nope/js/statics.js` here's the error:

```
`    qrc:/nope/js/statics.js: File not found`
or
`    qrc:/statics.js: File not found`
```

Now from inside the IDE things should be fine as it runs the executable inside the source code. The problems listed above here are in regards to deployment and there are MANY ways around that. I prefer this so I can run batch commands, you could also use `[OS]qtdeploy` tools and specify some paths to get around it.

This technique prevents the resource files from being recompiled every time you make a chance which can add HOURS to your workday if you're testing the QML. Copying files is fast and doesn't require bundling the resource file.

I hope this helps, I too, lost a few days to figuring this out a year and half ago.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your answer is a bit over my head, but it gives me somewhere to start. So are you saying that the best way to solve this problem is a way that will also help with future complexity/compilation issues. And that way is to 'bundle' my .js file by explicitly naming it in the CONFIG file. Thanks. I'll have to read up on the config file stuff. Thanks very much for your quick answer (no pun intended).

Comment: Yes, I'm saying down the road explicitly copying the javascript/images/etc... will speed things up. The resource files eventually will require a lot of time to compile (I had a 3-5 minute build which is why I moved to this approach). It sounds like you got it working though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure why my import needed the file to be in 'Resouces', others I've seen on youtube appeared to work without that. However, the code works now that I have added the .js file to resources by right clicking, not on resources but on the / folder within resources. Why didn't I try that before.
Thanks to both for help.

Comment: Your file is now working because the resource is now available on the path via the `Resources` file. just be aware that processing the Resources file takes time and if it becomes a burden you might want to look back at my answer, for a small project the compile-time is negligible.